# How to combine an update and sp_rename in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-update, substring, sp-rename

I have a SQL Server database `employeedb` and table `employee` with column `EmployeeID` whose value I need to update and simultaneously rename that column.

```
EmployeeID
-----------
83456785647
```

I need to add a `'-'` 2 digit places from the end and rename `EmployeeID` to `EmployeeNr` to get the below output

```
EmployeeNr
------------
834567856-47
```

I can achieve the desired outcome in step wise by running two separate SQL statements as:

```
update employee 
set EmployeeID = substring(cast(EmployeeID as varchar(255)), 1, len(cast(EmployeeID as varchar(255)))-2) + '-' + right(cast(EmployeeID as varchar(255)), 2)
```

and to change the column name I execute a separate query as:

```
USE employeedb;
GO

EXEC sp_rename 'employee.EmployeeID', 'EmployeeNr', 'COLUMN';
GO
```

Is there a way to combine both statements in a single SQL statement?

Comment: No, you are performing DML then DDL they are separate operations and presumably this is a one-off task...?

Comment: Yes it is a once-off task but I have many tables where I need to execute the queries with each table running into several millions of records. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps what you actually want is a computed column with that ID in it? Then you can just `ADD` the column and as it's computed, the values will be determined when needed.

Comment: You can do both in a transaction if you wish.

Comment: @Charlieface : How can I possibly do that?

Comment: `SET XACT_ABORT ON; BEGIN TRAN; UPDATE ...; EXEC sp_rename ..; COMMIT;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would, instead, suggest that you don't do either an `UPDATE` or rename the column; the ID is likely a primary key and being using for referencial integrity so changing its value *and* renaming it will likely break a wealth of things.

Instead add the "Nr" column as a calculated column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee
ADD EmployeeNr AS STUFF(EmployeeID, LEN(EmployeeID)-1,0,'-');
```

I also switch to `STUFF` to "inject" the character, as it seems a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will use your approach.